# AttributeError: 'Doc2Vec' object has no attribute 'dv'

Tags: python, gensim

I keep getting this error above. Some context... I have multiple top2vec models, and most are running completely fine (I have used the same environment for every model without changing a single thing). I have tried multiple versions of gensim. Any ideas or suggestions? I am working in Azure ML studio

Python Version
3.8

Gensim Versions tested
4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.1.2

Requirements.txt (These are added to a Tensorflow 2.7.0 docker image)

```
numpy==1.21.5
thinc==8.0.10
joblib==1.1.0
dill
click==8.0.4
gensim==4.1.2
top2vec[sentence_encoders]
```

Stack

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/top2vec/Top2Vec.py", line 2040, in 
query_topics
31
query_vec = self.model.infer_vector(doc_words=tokenized_query,
30
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gensim/models/doc2vec.py", line 628, in 
infer_vector
29
doctag_vectors = pseudorandom_weak_vector(self.dv.vector_size, seed_string=' 
'.join(doc_words))
28
AttributeError: 'Doc2Vec' object has no attribute 'dv'
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 2126, in 
shutdown

h.flush()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist- 
packages/opencensus/ext/azure/log_exporter/__init__.py", line 
109, 
in flush

if self._queue.is_empty():
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'is_empty'
```

Comment: Has that error message & traceback stack been edited down? (Usually there'd be more info.) How was your `model` created or loaded? Are you sure you're looking at the actually installed/active package versions in the active environment? (If run in the exact same interpreter/cell as you're getting the error, what does `import gensim; print("gensim", gensim.__version__)`show?)

Comment: Yes it has been edited down, that's really as much info I can give, and I have tested that (I should've mentioned that earlier), and the current version is 4.1.2. I may need to try gensim 4.2.0...

Comment: All versions of Gensim 4.0+ should have a `.dv` attribute. Have you double-checked that `import gensim; print("gensim", gensim.__version__)` prints the version you expect? More of the stack info might help diagnose what's gone wrong; it would be better to X-out anything you consider proprietary than delete it entirely (to better maintain context). Also, most importantly, knowing how your current `model` was created or loaded. (Improperly loading something from an older version might be a contributing factor.) But without such specific details, it's hard to guess what might be going wrong.

Comment: @gojomo, I am going to import and print directly into that file, and then I will post the full stack.

Comment: Yes, printing the effective Gensim version immediately before the line-that-fails is a good idea! But also, knowing the origin of the failing model (and its route into the current process) may be the key.

Comment: I am still learning how to use stack overflow and I can't post my redacted stack trace yet, but I added that line '''print("gensim", gensim.__version__)''', and it is printing the correct gensim version... The model is in a fileshare, so maybe it is a routing issue. There is another error with azure that I have seen too. I am adding to the post

Comment: You can edit your question, and place long verbatim (monospace-formatted) bits of code/logs, between 3-backticks. If you just replace any (minimal) proprietary ranges of code or filenames or system names with, say, `XXX`, that could help retain other useful non-proprietary context. With your latest edit, it seems there's a *new* (& probably unrelated!) error about a missing `is_empty` attribute. Best to keep each question focused on one particular issue/error at a time.